# Did Moses present himself at the highest peak of the mount?

Tags: exodus, moses

In Exodus 34:2 we read

> And be ready for the morning, and go up in the morning to Mount Sinai and **present yourself to me there on the top of the mountain**.

Does it mean at the highest peak of the mount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ideas that come together in Ex 34:2 -

**1. Top of the Mountain**

The operative word here is רֹאשׁ (rosh) meaning "head"; in the case of the mountain, it means "head of the mountain", that is, its top.  It is so used many times in the OT such as: Gen 8:5, 11:4, Ex 17:9, 19:20, 24:17, 34:2, Prov 1:21, 8:2, etc.

**2. Pillar of Cloud**

The pillar of cloud is mentioned numerous times in the Exodus narrative, eg, Ex 13:21, 22, 14:19, 24, 19:9, 33:9, 10, Num 9:15, 12:5, 14:14, Deut 1:33, 31:15, Neh 9:12.  It is often depicted as moving in some sense, either ahead of the Israelites as they traveled, behind them to protect against the Egyptian army.

In Ex 34:2 the pillar of cloud is depicted as descending on the mountain obviously from the direction of heaven/sky.  Whether this was the highest point of a convenient flat point on which Moses could stand is not stated.  However, we are given some further data.

In Ex 33:12-21 Moses asks to see God's glory (V18) but this request is denied because Moses would not live (V20).  Then God says to Moses (V21-23)

> The LORD continued, “There is a place near Me where you are to stand
> upon a rock, and when My glory passes by, I will put you in a cleft of
> the rock and cover you with My hand until I have passed by. Then I
> will take My hand away, and you will see My back; but My face must not
> be seen.”

Following this conversation, Ex 34:5-7 then describes what actually happened.  Note v6 -

> Then the LORD passed in front of Moses and called out: “The LORD, the
> LORD God, is compassionate and gracious, slow to anger, abounding in
> loving devotion and faithfulness,

Note that this occurred while Moses was in a 'cleft of the rock" (Ex 33:22) which cannot be the very highest point of the mountain but was close to it (Ex 33:21).  Thus Moses was in the "head of the mountain" very near the top.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **no**, as in verse 5 we read

> And **Yahweh descended in the cloud**, and he stood with him there, and he
> proclaimed the name of Yahweh.

Which seem to indicate that the cloud of Shekinah abode at peak.

However Moses probably had to be on a not so distant point of the summit.